# Set color to matplotlib patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm following [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/shapes_and_collections/patch_collection.html) tutorial by Matplotlib about patches. I understand how it works, but the only thing i don't understand is how can i set color to the patches. Say i want all of them to be orange, i tried this (from the code):

```
for x1, y1, r, t1, t2 in zip(x, y, radii, theta1, theta2):
    wedge = Wedge((x1, y1), r, t1, t2, color='orange')
    patches.append(wedge)
```

But it didn't set the color to the patches. How can i do that?

Comment: @JohanC the code is exactly the same as the example i linked; i only wanted to set the colors myself, but rest of the code is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify `match_original=True` (and of course comment out the line `p.set_array(np.array(colors))`). From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection):

> **match_original**
> If True, use the colors and linewidths of the original patches. If False, new colors may be assigned by providing the standard collection
> arguments, facecolor, edgecolor, linewidths, norm or cmap.

```
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.4, match_original=True)
```